# Leaflet: Shapefiles required to show shapes?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, shapefile, esri

I am facing a problem in loading shapefiles on Leaflet. Many examples on the Internet use a compressed shapefiles (.zip) containing these files:

- .shp
- .shx
- .dbf
- .prj
- .sbn
- .sbx
- .shp.xml

Many said that only .shp, .shx, and .dbf are mandatory so that Leaflet can show the shape on the map. One example working shapefiles can be found [here](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip). It consists of shp, shx, dbf, and prj.

Then I tried to use another shapefiles at [this page](http://www.geopostcodes.com/Indonesia) (click the sample data). The .zip file contains not only the shapefile but also the other files, so I took only the shapefile folder (contains shp, shx, dbf, and prj) and compressed them to form a new compressed file. Then, I put the file name as parameter to `L.Shapefile`

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.label.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet/leaflet.label.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet/leaflet.sprite.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet/leaflet.shpfile.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet/shp.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="map">
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-6.2398088,106.8152522], 10);   
    L.tileLayer('http://10.99.3.132/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
    var shpfile = new L.Shapefile("Shapefile.zip");
    shpfile.addTo(map);
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I use own tile server and have performed `chmod +x` to `Shapefile.zip` (I use Mac OSX 10.9.2 and Leaflet 0.7.3 with `leaflet.label`, `leaflet.sprite`, and `Leaflet.Shapefile` plugins)

Why is that so? The first shapefile that worked and the second shapefile that was compressed by myself contain the same number of file, and three necessary files (shp, shx, and dbf) are included in both of them. Am I missing something fundamental or important?

Any thought will be veeeery appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can't help you directly, but the "prj" file is optional and gives information on the shapefile projection. sbn and sbx are indexes and are also optional. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: You're setting the view to somewhere well outside the area covered by the sample data... Perhaps you're not seeing the shapefile because it's not in the view? Try something like [4.1325, 96.75]

Comment: @mlinth thanks for the response. Yap, I am sure that both my coordinate and yours covered the shape. Actually self-zipping is one of my concern. I've tried a working zipped shapefile, uncompressed it, and compressed it again and the new zip file is not working...

Comment: mandetory for the shapefile plugin is .shp, .dbf and if it isn't WGS84 .prj

Comment: dealing with shapefiles in browser is also why i prefer geojson/topojson; this may not be an option for you in this case, and i'm sure shapefiles have their merits in desktop apps, but using json takes all of these pains away.

Comment: yeah I was planning to switch to geojson, until I tried to compress the folder using zip command from shell instead of finder->right click on folder, and it worked for me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

zipping them on a mac added a folder called `__MACOSX` which has a file in it with the same name as the                                                                              other files but proceeded with a dot, it thinks this is a shapefile, fixed your shapefile should work on http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/